# Rails 3 / Heroku / Memcached - Miss / Miss,store / Fresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, caching, heroku, memcached

Good afternoon,

I have got Memcached set up decently well in my Heroku app.  However, there is some odd behaviour that makes me wonder whether or not I've got it set up correctly.

When I visit a page in my app (set up with caches_page), I get a miss, then miss/store, then fresh.  I feel like the first hit should be miss/store...

This is what I mean.  First visit:

```
2012-04-07T21:07:11+00:00 app[web.1]: Started GET "/help" for xx.xx.xx.xx at 2012-04-07 21:07:11 +0000
2012-04-07T21:07:11+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /help] miss
```

Second visit:

```
2012-04-07T21:07:16+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /help] miss, store
```

Third visit:

```
2012-04-07T21:07:19+00:00 app[web.1]: cache: [GET /help] fresh
```

I'm not sure if this is actually a problem, or if I should go about my merry way.  Thanks!

Comment: Not a rails expert, but you should look at the HTTP headers you're sending along the request. If they are different between the 3 requests this may be a clue as to why the first miss isn't a "miss, store".

Comment: As far as I know, Heroku doesn't actually support page caching. You have to use Rack::Cache with expires_in headers or use action caching. The miss, miss/store, fresh may be unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

With anything to do with caching, the first thing to do is always to inspect the response headers (you can use browser dev tools for this).

My guess is the first request is returning a set-cookie header for the rails session, which is causing rack cache to treat the response as uncacheable, and for good reason. The subsequent request does not return set-cookie since there already is a session, and rack cache stores it. The third request hits the previously cached content.